# Custom data types in Irony language

Tags: .net, irony

I'm trying to build a language using Irony. The problem I'm facing is that I want my language to have some built-in data types (not just strings and mubers, but also some custom objects with properties etc.) In ExpressionEvaluator I see how built-in methods can be added, but I don't see how built-in data types can be added.